# Rails Routes Generating Path from Object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, path, routes

I'm having trouble generating a url form an object.

I have following code in my routes file:

`match '(*path)/:name' => 'pages#show'`

Which directs to my `Page` controller containing:

```
def show
    if params[:path] and params[:name]
      @page = Page.where(:path => params[:path], :title => params[:name]).first
    elsif params[:name]
      @page = Page.where(:path => "", :title => params[:name]).first
    end
end
```

So in the case of `localhost:3000/food/` will find the page where `:path => "", :title => 'food'`

And `localhost:3000/food/pizza` will find the page where `:path => "food/", :title => 'pizza'`

---

The problem is trying get a url generated from the a `Page` object.
So `link_to(@page.title, @page)` returns:

`undefined method 'page_path'`

How do I get the route to work in reverse to generate a url form an object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to fall back to the 'old-style' link_to:

```
link_to @page.title, :controller => "pages", :action => "show", :path => @page.path, :name => @page.title %>
```

see: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to under examples

Also, check out http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default to see if you *realy* want to go down that road with your routes

Comment: Thanks, this works great - It breaks when path="" but an if clause removing the :path hash fixes that.